# When Knit Rmarkdown, illustrations and table titles are garbled

Tags: r

I downloaded the rmarkdown document of senior xieyihui, and knit the index in it, and the knit was successful, but some garbled characters appeared on the loaded HTML page, mainly on the titles of pictures and tables.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtMYd.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55mkn.png)

I installed texlive2022 on my computer, and set the encoding of R to utf8. I can't find the problem, and I hope to get support from the community.